# SPFX Listview Command Set getValues for a selected file

Tags: spfx, power-automate, listviewcommandset

I have created a custom SPFX ListView Command Set button which triggers a flow (using http request) when a file is selected in SharePoint. Currently it sends information about the file ID, file name, and the url of the file. I have been trying to get the values Modified By so I know who modified the file and the value if its a folder or file. I have not been able to do this yet, and cannot really find any documenation for what you can get from the event.selectedRows. This is the code I have so far to retrieve values:

```
let documentServerRelativeUrl = event.selectedRows[0].getValueByName('FileRef');
let fileName = JSON.stringify(event.selectedRows[0].getValueByName('FileLeafRef'));
let fileID = JSON.stringify(event.selectedRows[0].getValueByName('ID'));
let isFolder = JSON.stringify(event.selectedRows[0].getValueByName('FieldType'));
let modifiedBy = JSON.stringify(event.selectedRows[0].getValueByName('Modified By'));
```

FieldType and Modified By are both returning empty values. Any idea on how I could get the modified by name and whether its a file or folder?

Comment: Just a suggestion - since you're getting value of item ID, can't you use a REST API call to retrieve other document properties?

Comment: @MatiurRahman Yes I can, but I am trying to avoid this multi-step process and trying to do it all at once. Also in flow I am able to use Get File using the ID, but for some reason am unable to get the values back to use as dynamic content in the rest of the flow. Might have to ask a question about this on the power automate forums.